# How can you make an object disappear in ROBLOX over a certain interval?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a game in ROBLOX, which has a cutscene in it at the start. At the end of the cutscene, the camera zooms up on the character and you spawn in. However, when I spawn in, I can see the dummy I used for the cutscene, so how after a certain interval can you make that dummy disappear?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It would be best if you could edit your question so we can see your current code as well as what you have tried. Otherwise, we can't help you with what is essentially a "please send the code" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the dummy just need to become invisible? If so, every physical object in ROBLOX (or more formally [Part](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Part)) has a [.Transparency](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/BasePart/Transparency) field that spans from **0** (for no transparency) to **1** (for full transparency, or in other words, **invisible**). I don't know what your "dummy" looks like in the object hierarchy, but let's say your dummy were a [Model](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Model) located at `workspace.dummy`, and that it has a head, torso, left arm, etc. located at `workspace.dummy.Head`, `workspace.dummy.Torso`, `workspace.dummy.LeftArm`, etc. To make the Parts of the dummy invisible, you would have code that looks like this:

```
workspace.dummy.Head.Transparency = 1
workspace.dummy.Torso.Transparency = 1
workspace.dummy.LeftArm.Transparency = 1
...
```

And so on. **This, however, will make the dummy invisible to all players.** If you are making a single-player game, this will not matter; however, if it is a multiplayer game, then this could be a problem. **Making the dummy non-transparent again to do the cutscene for a new player would make the dummy visible to all players.** If this is a problem for you, there are two things you could do that I know of:

The first and *easiest* way would be to just have the cutscene take place at a location very far away from where your game occurs; for example, you could shift everything in your cutscene 10,000 studs in the X direction. This would ensure the objects in the cutscene would be out of the render distance of the players playing the actual game, so only the players whose cameras are being manipulated to carry out the cutscene would see it.

The second, more complicated, and **not future-proof** option involves a very useful bug that is frequently taken advantage of but subject to being fixed at any time since it is not an official feature. This bug is the exploitation of a [Camera](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Camera) (or less commonly a [Message](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Message), which is deprecated) to create what are called **local parts**—Parts *only visible to a certain player*. How to create local parts and discussion of benefits and consequences of using local parts is a little complicated and beyond the scope of this answer. Go [here](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=Local_parts#How_to_make_your_own_Local_Parts) if you'd like to learn more. Taken directly from the [ROBLOX Wiki](http://wiki.roblox.com) at the time of writing:

> Local parts are **in no way supported by Roblox**. They exploit unspecified replication behaviour - at any given moment, the development team could release an update that changes how Camera and Message instances behave, preventing you from making local parts.